# как поменять запрос? react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
export const exportDrafts = async ({
  userRole,
  type,
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  filterForm,
}: ExportDraftInput) => {
  const params: ExportDraftRequestPayload = { type };
  if (dateFrom) {
    params.from = dateFrom;
  }
  if (dateTo) {
    params.to = dateTo;
  }
  if (type) {
    params.type = type;
  }
  if (filterForm) {
    params['form'] = filterForm; // тут ошибка Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
  }

  const response = await api.get<Blob>(`/${userRole}/insurance-drafts/export`, {
    params,
    responseType: "blob",
  });

  const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/zip" });
  saveAs(blob, `drafts_${dayjs().format("DD-MM-YYYY_HH-mm-ss")}.xlsx`);
};
```

на данный момент filterForm имеет тип string[] (массив строк)
и в типах form тоже объявлена как string[]

я пыталась заменить пустой массив на пустую строку или убрать вообще условие, но это не так работает, видимо((

```js
const filterForm = useMemo(
  () => (qsFilterForm ? qsFilterForm.split(",") : []),
  [qsFilterForm]
);
```

но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в теле запроса было не ?type=mytype&form[]=standard, а ?type=mytype&form=standard

без этого массива после слова форм
как это можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите, как вы эту строку формируете?

Comment: Не надо пожалуйста вставлять воспроизводимый код, который не воспроизводится

Comment: @SwaD добавила вот код запроса, на данный момент пишет оишбку - указала там в коде

Comment: Какой смысл в `const filterForm = useMemo`? Как понимаю, вы получаете строку, преобраузете ее в массив, разбивая через ',' и возвращаете полученный массив. Отсюда и ошибка с типами. Зачем вы строку превращаете в массив?

Comment: @SwaD эта часть кода не моя(( не знала, что это может быть не нужно. получается, я это вообще могу убрать?

Comment: Попробуйте во всяком случае. Не зная, зачем вы это делаете и для чего, а так же, какие данные изнчально приходят, сложно сказать.

Comment: @Swad в фильтрФорм приходят две строки - в зависимости от выставленного фильтра. Это нужно для того, чтобы далее передать отфильтрованные данные и скачать таблицу эксель с актулаьными данными (которые именно сейчас показываются на экране, с учетом фильтра)

Comment: В любом случае, params['form'] ожидает тип данных - строка.

Comment: @SwaD поняла! спасибо! а скажите, пожалуйста, нельзя ли как-то сделать так, чтобы получать form[] как массив, допутим, но игнорировать, что это массив и воспринимать строкой?

то есть сейчас в моем реквесте написано form[]=standard, он возможно ли так сделать, чтобы оно менялось как бы динамически на это form=standard?

Comment: Попробуйте передать строку, может оно само поменяется?